# xcode build on iphone testbed clears documents files

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am building and testing directly on a iphone 3.0 and it works fine. only issue is the JPEG files my app creates in the documents directory seem to be disappearing. This is odd because I have a sqlite db file in the same directory that seems to be there all the time.

The files disappear the first build after I take the photos and save them to the documents path. If I close the app manually and click the icon on the springboard, the files still show up as they should.

What is causing this and can it be prevented? I have to test on an iphone to test the camera functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was saving the absolute path. Thing is, the document path changes every time, so now I save the relative path and get the current documents path every time I load the image file.